# IOS dynamically send the filename uploading the file in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, file-upload

Here I have to send the file name dynamically while uploading the file, when i try to upload the hard coded file name, the file is moved successfully, but when i pass the file name in dynamic the file corrupted.

Please verify my code.

```
  NSMutableData *postBody = [NSMutableData data];

// -------------------- ---- Audio Upload Status ---------------------------\\
//pass MediaType file

[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; userfile=\"file upload\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n",audioName] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[@"Content-Type: audio/m4a\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[@"Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:audioData];
```

Comment: Can you print the log of audioName..pls give the log

Comment: Thanks for your response.log is "audioName :Audio0.m4a"

Comment: You can pass file content in multipart post and file name in service url.

Comment: s sir i am using multipart only, for more reference i share my full code in above

Comment: is "audioName:Audio0.m4a" is going as name insted of "Audio0.m4a"

Comment: s sir, the audio name is going as  "Audio0.m4a"

Comment: Accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

At finally I findout my answer, its my mistake i missed to concate the format ".m4a" string

NSMutableData *postBody = [NSMutableData data];

```
// -------------------- ---- Audio Upload Status ---------------------------\\
//pass MediaType file

[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; userfile=\"file upload\"; filename=\"%@.m4a\"\r\n",audioName] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[@"Content-Type: audio/m4a\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:[@"Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postBody appendData:audioData];
```

Now its working well